# Extract % from character column in R data frame

Tags: r, regex

I have column seller_details in a data frame.
An example of the data in the `seller_details` column is:

```
1. 8ysl9a1301 Active 3 hours ago chat now view shop Ratings10products996 response rate28% response
2. showcasemywardore Active 3 hours ago chat now view shop Ratings773products5k response rate70% response
3. zanzea.os Active 37 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings290.5kproducts6.6k response rate93% response
4. airspacemy.os Active 14 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings1.2kproducts2k response rate70% response
5. zanzea.os Active 37 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings290.5kproducts6.6k response rate93% response
```

I want to extract the percentage of response rate only.

Expected output:

```
1. 28
2. 70
3. 93
4. 70
5. 93
```

Thank you

#### Data

```r
structure(list(seller_details = c("8ysl9a1301 Active 3 hours ago chat now view shop Ratings10products996 response rate28% response", 
"showcasemywardore Active 3 hours ago chat now view shop Ratings773products5k response rate70% response", 
"zanzea.os Active 37 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings290.5kproducts6.6k response rate93% response", 
"airspacemy.os Active 14 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings1.2kproducts2k response rate70% response", 
"zanzea.os Active 37 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings290.5kproducts6.6k response rate93% response"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(percent = str_extract(col, '(?<=rate)\\d{2,3}'))
                                                                                                     col percent
1        8ysl9a1301 Active 3 hours ago chat now view shop Ratings10products996 response rate28% response      28
2 showcasemywardore Active 3 hours ago chat now view shop Ratings773products5k response rate70% response      70
3 zanzea.os Active 37 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings290.5kproducts6.6k response rate93% response      93
4 airspacemy.os Active 14 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings1.2kproducts2k response rate70% response      70
5 zanzea.os Active 37 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings290.5kproducts6.6k response rate93% response      93
```

Data used:

```
df
                                                                                                     col
1        8ysl9a1301 Active 3 hours ago chat now view shop Ratings10products996 response rate28% response
2 showcasemywardore Active 3 hours ago chat now view shop Ratings773products5k response rate70% response
3 zanzea.os Active 37 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings290.5kproducts6.6k response rate93% response
4 airspacemy.os Active 14 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings1.2kproducts2k response rate70% response
5 zanzea.os Active 37 minutes ago chat now view shop Ratings290.5kproducts6.6k response rate93% response
```

Comment: (1) Why not looking for a `%`? (2) Isn't `\\d+` more appropriate? Percentage could by `5%` or  `1230%`?

Comment: @MartinGal, the string has "response rate", it can't go beyond 100%

Comment: Good point. Nevertheless `5%` is still a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly this is verbose compared to the solution posted by Kathis S.
But you can try using base R's gsub function.

```
gsub("(^\\d+)(.*)(\\d{2})(%)(\\s[a-z]*)", "\\1 \\3", seller_details, perl = TRUE)
```

The parenthesis act as groups.

```
Group one:  (^\\d)
Group two: (.*)
Group three: (\\d{2})
Group four (%)
Group five (\\s[a-z]*)
```

The string to replace is \1 \3, which refer to the group numbers as stated above.
You want to return group 1. A number, one time at the start of the string.
And group 3, a number with two digits, which is followed by a %.

Group five is necessary to capture the end of the string, in your case, the word "response".

There are probably cleaner ways to do this, but it will work nonetheless.